# Awk syntax error when command is executed through a shell script however the command works fine when executed from Linux bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am running this command

```
awk '{print "Removing " ORS $0;system("rm " $0 ORS  " if [ $? -eq 0 ]" ORS "then" ORS "echo file  " $0 " has been removed." ORS "fi")}' <(cat /tmp/findo)
```

On bash and the command works however when executed from a shell script it throws the underlying error

Here is the example and you may look at the 'line 23 error'

```
# sh -x rvarlog_util.sh
+ findout=/tmp/findout
+ '[' -e /tmp/findout ']'
++ du -sm /var/log
++ awk '{print $1+0}'
+ cdu=2372
++ awk '{print $1+0}'
++ grep total
++ du -m --max-depth=1 -c -m -x /var/log/messages /var/log/messages-20190310 /var/log/messages-20190323-1553338190.gz /var/log/messages-20190324-1553424406.gz /var/log/messages-20190324-1553456095.gz /var/log/messages-20190324-1553456293.gz /var/log/messages-20190324-1553457237.gz /var/log/messages-20190324-1553457268.gz /var/log/maillog-20190324-1553456095.gz /var/log/boot.log /var/log/audit/audit.log /var/log/audit/audit.log-20190311-1552325090.gz /var/log/puppetlabs
+ fusage=2258
rvarlog_util.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `('
rvarlog_util.sh: line 23: `awk '{print "Removing " ORS $0;system("rm " $0 ORS  " if [ $? -eq 0 ]" ORS "then" ORS "echo file  " $0 " has been removed." ORS "fi")}' <(cat /tmp/findo)'
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: awk '{print "Removing " ORS $0;system("rm " $0 ORS " if [ $? -eq 0 ]" ORS "then" ORS "echo file " $0 " has been removed." ORS "fi")}' <(cat /tmp/findout) is the command. Are you saying I should be formatting line 23 specifically?

Comment: See the link in my comment above for details of how to make your code above display correctly.

Comment: Sure, thank you . Let me format.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly on some earlier line of your shell script that you aren't showing us, e.g. a missing quote. Post a [mcve] shell script that reproduces the error. Using shell to call awk to call system to call shell to call rm is a terrible idea btw - just call rm directly from shell.

Comment: As Ed says the syntax error must be from preceding line. If I copy only your awk command in a script, it works correctly.

Comment: Ed, I've been told calling rm directly from a shell using a shell  script isn't a good idea, thus I was looking for options and found this one. I could probably use a while loop to read each line from the output file and invoke the rm command considering what you said

Comment: This sounds a lot like an XY-problem.

Comment: I guarantee no-one ever told you that calling rm directly from a shell using a shell script isn't a good idea, you must have misunderstood what someone was trying to tell you about some aspect of HOW you were doing that. Yes, you could use a while loop or xargs

Comment: @ArnoBozo, Why would the debug run then print syntax error on line 23?.

Comment: if you remove the awk command from your script, do you still see some syntax error?

Comment: Imagine you have code like `echo "hello; awk 'BEGIN{print " world"}'` on 2 separate lines. There's nothing wrong with the line containing `awk` but that's the first place the shell can recognize there's a syntax problem and so reports it on that line. The shell doesn't know that the problem was really caused by the missing `"` on the `echo` line since THAT is not a syntax error - it's perfectly valid syntax to have a multi-line string but in this case that string terminates half-way through the awk command and so what's left of the awk command is reported as the syntax error.

Comment: Dear @ronythomas, welcome to Stack Overflow. What you are attempting is extremely convoluted for a rather straightforward task. It seems your file `/tmp/findout` is the result of a simple `find` command. Parsing the output of a `find` command is not-done (simlilar to [not parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). Whatever your find command is, you could just use something like : `find <your args> -printf "Deleting %f\n" -delete`

Comment: Upload your shell script to shellcheck.net and see what it finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ibraheem has the right solution, but so far nobody's spotted the problem. It's that you're using a process substitution (`<(cat /tmp/findo)`), but running the script with `sh` rather than `bash`. Process substitution isn't available in all shells (or even bash when it's invoked as "sh").

There are a couple of ways to fix this, and I'd recommend doing both ('cause they're good ideas on their own):

- Don't use `<(cat somefile)`, use a plain redirect, like `<somefile`. The process-substituted `cat` command is an overly complex, fragile, and inefficient way to read from a file.
- Give the script a proper shebang line (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), make it executable (`chmod +x rvarlog_util.sh`), and run it directly by entering its path (`./rvarlog_util.sh`) rather than explicitly specifying a shell (`sh` or `bash`). In general, the script should "know" which shell it's written for, and overriding that (by explicitly specifying a shell when you run it) is a bad idea.

Comment: Quite a few shells support `<(command)`, actually, not just bash. (dash, used for `/bin/sh` on Debian, Ubuntu, and many other linux distributions isn't one of them, though.)

Comment: @Shawn Wow, I had no idea, but at least `zsh` and `ksh` 93 both support process substitution. I'll edit my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 2):

from your awk command, what I understood that you are trying to remove files who's names found in  /tmp/findo file, is that correct? then replace your awk command with below code and see if it works, BUT make sure that the file names in `/tmp/findo` contain absolute path to the required files you are trying to remove

```
while read -r files
do
  rm "$files" 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
  then
     "echo $files has been removed."
  fi
done < /tmp/findo
```

Comment: I'd recommend double-quoting `$files` both times it's used (and for the `echo` command, double-quote the entire string). Also, you can simplify it by testing the result of `rm` directly: `if rm "$files"`.

Comment: Or simpler: `xargs -d'\n' rm -v </tmp/findo`

Comment: @Wiimm this one liner does the job, thank you very much

Comment: @ronythomas welcome, you can accept the answer if that is all you needed,